# Reflection principle for finite subsystems of PA.

Tags: logic, proof-theory, formal-proofs, provability, sequent-calculus

I would like to clarify the reasoning behind the proof of **reflection schema** for finite subsystems of **PA** that I found in *"The Blind Spot"* book.

To be wore precise, we have a finite subsystem $\mathcal{T}$ of **PA**, and a formula $A$ with one free variable, predicate $\text{Thm}_{\mathcal{T}}(x)$ expressing a provability in $\mathcal{T}$ of the formula with the Gödel number $x$. The we want to prove a statement that **PA** proves $\text{Thm}_{\mathcal{T}}(\ulcorner A[\bar{x}]\urcorner)\Rightarrow A[x]$, where $\ulcorner x\urcorner$ is a Gödel number for $x$.

The reasoning started with noticing that axioms of $\mathcal{T}$ can be packed into a formula $B$, and noticing that the provability of a formula $C$ in $\mathcal{T}$ reduces to the provability of $B\Rightarrow C$ in sequent calculus **LK** (here it's also not super clear, but has some sense for me as $\mathcal{T}$ is finitely axiomatizable). Then, as I understand, we say that the provability of $B\Rightarrow C$ in sequent calculus **LK** transforms into the fact of provability of $B\Rightarrow C$ in **PA** (this is the **first** more or less vague step where I'd like to have more comments, but I assume it's connected to the fact that provability in **LK** is transformed to that of in **PA** by induction).

Therefore, we have $\text{Thm}_{\textbf{LK}}(\ulcorner B\Rightarrow A[\bar{x}]\urcorner)\Rightarrow(B\Rightarrow A[x])$. And the **second** question is about transforming this fact into the one in the theorem statement (where I also only have a slight guess that we do have $B$ on our hands in **PA**, but still there is something to say).

I would be glad for any comments and suggestions.